# fromEvent() not triggering observable on ViewChild?

Tags: angular, rxjs6

I have the following in *app.component.html*

```
 <label class="label">Trigger Observables: </label>
 <div class="control">
   <input class='input is-primary' type='text' placeholder="enter some text" (input)='obs4chain()' #inp/>
 </div>
```

And in *app.component.ts*

```
obs4chain(){
  this.clearSubscription();
  const observable = fromEvent(document, 'input');

  this.subscription = observable.pipe(
    map(<InputEvent>(eventInfo) => eventInfo.target.value),
    debounceTime(500),
    distinctUntilChanged()
  ).subscribe(
    (evt) => console.log(evt)
  );

}
```

This code works fine and as expected, however in the case of having more than one input field I only want a specific one so using the local ref and viewchild so I have:

```
@ViewChild('inp') myInput: ElementRef;
```

And adjust my obervable declaration like so: `const observable = fromEvent(this.myInput.nativeElement, 'input');`

I can see that with viewChild I'm passing in the native html element of input rather than listening to the entire document which should work according to the docs:

> fromEvent accepts as a first argument event target, which is an object with methods for registering event handler functions.

So I'm not sure why in this case the observable fails to create. Any ideas?

---

**Edit** Following @bryan60's example and refactoring my own code I noticed something.

Subscribing immediately after making the observable has the intended behavior:

```
  const observable = fromEvent(this.myInput.nativeElement, 'input').pipe(
    map(<InputEvent>(eventInfo) => eventInfo.target.value),
    debounceTime(500),
    distinctUntilChanged()
  ).subscribe(
    (evt) => console.log(evt)
  );
```

But storing it as a var and subscribing after does not:

```
  let observable = fromEvent(this.myInput.nativeElement, 'input').pipe(
    map(<InputEvent>(eventInfo) => eventInfo.target.value),
    debounceTime(500),
    distinctUntilChanged()
  );
  this.subscription = observable.subscribe(
    (evt) => console.log(evt)
  );
```

And I'm still not sure why that is.

Comment: code works as intended: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7-master-n3y67g?file=src/app/app.component.ts that said... there are many other ways to react to input value changes that are far more "angular" approaches (reactive forms valueChanges, ngModel on change)

Comment: I editted my question following your example. It seems like breaking it apart into a declaration of the observable and then subscribing fails. @bryan60

Comment: dunno. still can't recreate in stackblitz. saving in a variable still works for me.

Comment: I wonder if it's just a version thing at this point. I'm using Angular 6 and rxjs6.

Comment: not sure. looks like more of a logical error in how you're calling the function to build the observable, or you're possibly breaking the reference somehow

Comment: So I think I figured it out, adding the callback behaviour and observable declaration to `ngAfterViewInit` fixed my problem. I think the problem is I'm calling `fromEvent()` on an event from within an event using event binding, something with how that's nested isn't playing nicely

Comment: ViewChild(ren) aren’t available till the afterviewinit hook... so that might’ve been your problem if you were trying to build this with an uninitialized viewchild. But that should have thrown an error of some kind unless it was getting swallowed somewhere